# Cat command in ubuntu

Tags: 18.04

cat -b command is for adding number of lines while cat -E for $ sign if i want to see the number of lines of one file and see the $ sign for other then how can it be done?                       "if i write cat -b file1 -E file2" it shows the result as that of file one and of file2

Answer (score 0):

Make it a subshell with two `cat` commands in parentheses:

```
( cat -b file1 ; cat -E file2 )
```